# Справка из комментариев

Tags: документация, java, c#

Недавно перешел из отдела Java в отдел C#. Не заметил, чтобы документация создавалась из комментариев. Не хватает JavaDoc. Наверняка в C# есть похожая вещь. Где посмотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналог JavaDoc (если я правильно понимаю, что это такое) - это [SandeCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/), подробнее - в [справке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b2s063f7.aspx) по генерации документации.